# Conservation law of equation involving Hilbert transform

Tags: conservation-laws

I am trying to confirm a conservation law I cam across in a paper (Janssen 1983 "On a fourth-order envelope equation for deep-water waves" Journal Fluid Mechanics), and am having difficulty.

In particular, I'm trying to confirm the conservation of linear momentum $P$, where

$P = \frac{i}{2} \int AA^*_x - A^*A_x \ dx$,

where $^*$ denotes complex conjugate and spatial integrals are taken to be over all space in this question. Now, the governing equation takes the form

$A_t = \mathcal{N}(A,A^*) - P.V. \  i\alpha\ A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial|A|^2}{\partial x'}\frac{1}{x-x'} \ dx'$,

where $\mathcal{N}$ is a (nonlinear) operator describing the rest of the dynamics, which is not important for this question, P.V. denotes the principal value and $\alpha$ is some real constant. Note, this integral is proportional to the Hilbert transform.

Now, I want to look at the time evolution of the momentum $P$. To that end, we have

$\frac{d P}{dt} = \frac{i}{2} \int  \dot{A}A^*_x +A\dot{A}_x^* -\dot{A}^*A_x -A^*\dot{A}_x \ dx$

Substituting in the relation for our governing equation, and using integration by parts (we assume the field A is compact) we find

$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{\alpha}{2} \int  (|A|^2)_x \mathcal{H} (|A|^2_x) \ dx$

where

$\mathcal{H}(|A|^2_x) \equiv P.V. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial|A|^2}{\partial x'}\frac{1}{x-x'} \ dx'$.

Now, this term is non-zero, where as the author claims this integral is conserved. I don't see why this integral should vanish, but perhaps I'm not exploiting a property of the Hilbert transform.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: By the way, could you edit the question to include a link to the relevant paper, just for the benefit of possible future readers who might be interested?

Comment: Done - can you add a reference for the anti-self-adjoint property you pointed out?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Anti-self_adjointness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{H}$ is anti-self-adjoint, we have

$$\langle F,\mathcal{H}F\rangle=\frac{\langle F,\mathcal{H}F\rangle-\langle \mathcal{H}F,F\rangle}{2}=0$$
since $F=|A|_x^2$ is real.

Thus $\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{\alpha}{2}\langle F,\mathcal{H}F\rangle=0$ (unless I'm misreading your notation).